Zustand in Next JS: state is cleared when navigating to a page that doesn't exist
Please help me figure this out:
Im using zustand in Next JS to store the global state - user data.
I save the data in the local storage via persist middleware from zustand.
Everything works fine, BUT when I go to a page that does not exist (shows a not found error) - the global state is reset.
Then it is restored from the local storage - but after 1-2 seconds pass.
Accordingly, all the functionality tied to this state - blinks.
I configured store in a separate TS file (store.ts):
export const useStore = createWithEqualityFn<IUserStore>()(
  persist(
    (set) => ({
      user: null,

      setUser: (data) => {
        set({ user: data });
      },
      removeUser: () => set({ user: null }),
    }),
    {
      name: "user",
    }
  ),
  shallow
);

I tried to pass the store via context - it didn't help.
I tried to make custom not-found.tsx error with "use client".
